# How to 'Post' form data into 2 tables in database

Tags: c#, razor, controller, asp.net-apicontroller

I need to add my form data from html into 2 tables in the database when I click the save button. My problem is the data does not get saved into any tables

This is the html part :

```
$('#saveButton').on('click', function () {
    var collectedAccountName = $('#accountNameInput').val();
    var collectedDatepicker = $('#datepicker').val();
    var collectedRatePerHour = $('#ratePerHourInput').val();
    var collectedComment = $('#commentsInput').val();
    var collectedIsVisible = $('#togBtn').prop('checked');

        var webFormData = new WebFormData(collectedAccountName, collectedDatepicker, collectedRatePerHour,
            collectedComment, collectedIsVisible);

        var webFormDataInString = JSON.stringify(webFormData);

        $saveCustomerAccountHandler = jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/API/CustomerAccounts/',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: "'" + webFormDataInString + "'"
    })//end of ajax() call
```

This is the API controller HTTPPOST

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        dynamic customerAccountNewInput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(value);
        CustomerAccount newCustomerAccount = new CustomerAccount();
        AccountRate newAccountRate = new AccountRate();
        try
        {
            newCustomerAccount.AccountName = customerAccountNewInput.AccountName.Value;
            newCustomerAccount.CreatedById = userId;
            newCustomerAccount.UpdatedById = userId;
            newCustomerAccount.Comments = customerAccountNewInput.Comment.Value;
            newCustomerAccount.IsVisible = customerAccountNewInput.IsVisible;
            newAccountRate.EffectiveStartDate = customerAccountNewInput.Datepicker.Value;
            newAccountRate.RatePerHour = customerAccountNewInput.RatePerHour.Value;
            Database.CustomerAccounts.Add(newCustomerAccount);
            Database.AccountRates.Add(newAccountRate);
            Database.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          throw ex
        }
```

Database

[image: Picture of customer account database]

[image: Picture of account rate database]

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If you put a breakpoint at action then does your action hit while debugging?

Comment: We do not know what is this `Database` class, how can we answer your question?

Comment: @user1672994 yes if i put a breakpoint at action it hits while debugging

Comment: @omriman12 which database class are you referring to? Kindly tell me i'll add it in thanks

Comment: @Jasper here: `Database.CustomerAccounts`. What is the code of the `Database`, I understand you use `EF` right?

Comment: @omriman12 I added the picture of the database is that the correct one? Yes I use EF